# Android stop service

Tags: android, service

I have a service that runs when my app first starts that extends `AccessibilityService`, and I have put in booleans of course to not read when the user manually shuts off the app (by my button), but I noticed that if they just clear the recent used apps, it doesn't shut off my service, so how would I make it so if they force close my app that it shuts off my service?

Answer (score 0):

You should stop your service in onDestroy of the activity.

More details in android documentation:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Lifecycle